# I Can't Get Root Back After Trying To Modify The Hosts File

Tags: root-access, lineageos, magisk

I have a Motorola Edge (regular not +) running LineageOS 17.1 (20210528). I had it rooted and decided I wanted to use the hosts file for ad blocking. I couldn't figure out how to get the OS to allow me to modify the host file. While I was doing so, I somehow corrupted to OS and couldn't boot into it. That was easily fixed by flashing the the OS, but now I can't get root back. When I reboot after I flash the Magisk patched boot.img (to both partitions), I get "Can't load Android system. Your data maybe corrupt..." (This happens when I try to boot into both partitions). Before I see the error message, it goes into a bootloop for a few minutes.

Thanks

Comment: format userdata

Comment: Could you tell me why something on that partition is preventing me from rooting my phone?   And what that something might be?       Thanks

Comment: you have installed magisk which destroyed encryption therefore phone is in boot loop unsucessful trying to decrypt until you start with a fresh formatted unencrypted partition

Comment: to undo magisk changes and fix encryption flash stock vendor (or restore fstab manually)

Comment: I fixed it a few days later. I don't know exactly what did it, but while the stock ROM was installed, I flashed the Magisk uninstall in TWRP. Then when I rebooted the phone, it booted into the LineageOS recovery and showed the  "Can't load Android system. Your data maybe corrupt..."  error message. I chose to do the factory reset and when the phone rebooted, to my shock and amazement, it booted into LineageOS! I got  it rooted again and everything is back to normal. I'm thinking it was flashing the Magisk uninstall zip that fixed it, but that's only a guess.

Comment: I think you solved it with fresh formatted unencrypted userdata partition

Comment: I think It was flashing the Magisk uninstsller that solved it, but you could be right.